# Помогите обвязать библиотеку с Activity

Tags: java, android

Прошу Вас помочь мне обвязать библиотеку с активити.

[вот библиотека AESCrypt](https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android/blob/master/aescrypt/src/main/java/com/scottyab/aescrypt/AESCrypt.java)

Я собственно остановился на activity_main.
В MainActivity.java подключил только кнопки. А как дальше их обвязывать не могу понять. (нуб...)

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText inputText, inputPassword;
    TextView outputText;
    Button encBtn, decBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
        encBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.encBtn);
        decBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decBtn);

        }
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter encrypt text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputText"
    android:hint="Enter encrypt password" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/outputText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/encBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Encrypt"
    android:layout_below="@id/outputText" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/decBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Decrypt"
    android:layout_below="@id/encBtn" />
```

Comment: что значит обвязать, повесить им слушателя? Чтобы по нажатию выполнялось действие?

Comment: да.я не могу понять с чего начать писать метод.

Comment: а причём тут AESCrypt?

Comment: Мне кажется вам сперва стоит обратить внимание на документацию, https://developer.android.com/, посмотреть обучающие видеокурсы по Android, видимо вам не хватает базовых навыков и понятий, а в один ответ их не уложить.

Comment: да, знаний действительно не хватает. поэтому решил спросить

Comment: Здесь отвечают на более конкретные вопросы, для реализации клика вам нужно добавить этот слушатель https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener, но скорее всего данная ссылка вам ничего не даст, поэтому советую посмотреть курсы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
encBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.encBtn);
...
encBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG","do something");
        }
    });
```

Типо этого